# Call SOAP API using php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have one WSDL file. file url is given below

```
http://home.nutselect.nl/services/DossierService.svc?wsdl
```

I need to get the order details from this wsdl file. but when call this soap WSDL file i got the empty window only.

Any one please help me. How to get the Order details from this soap WSDL file.

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://home.nutselect.nl/services/DossierService.svc?wsdl');
    $response = $client->Request();

    print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Saravana all you need to do is generate a php class form the wsdl. and when you inherit the class you can probably get the public methods.

Check this link for the php class generator

https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator